# Filter Hangfire succeded job list

Tags: hangfire

Is there a way to have a job ***not*** appear in the Succeeded Job list?

I currently have 2 recurring jobs set up as follows:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("myQuickJob", () => CallRemoteService(quickCheckUrl)), Cron.Minutely());

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("myDailyJob", () => CallRemoteService(dailyJobUrl)), Cron.Daily(0));
```

One is a daily scheduled job the other is a quick ping job. I am really only interested in the results (success/fail) of the daily job and not the quick job.
As you can imagine the resuls of the quick job very quickly fill up the Job list with hundreds of succeeded calls of which I am not interested and it gets hard to isolate the daily jobs.

So, is there a way to:

1. Turn off the job log/display of the quick job
2. Have the name of the job show up in the list.

My job listing only shows all entries like:

```
#238  Startup.CallRemoteService  7.234s  13 minutes ago  
#237  Startup.CallRemoteService  7.424s  23 minutes ago
```

so I can't distinguish between the `myQuickJob` and the `myDailyJob`. Can the Job name be changed in the listing so I see `myDailyJob` instead of `Startup.CallRemoteService` ?

ta

Answer (score 0):

First of all, regarding your second problem the answer is quite easy: use a proxy method as below

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
                 "myQuickJob", 
                 () => CallRemoteServiceQuickCheck(quickCheckUrl)), Cron.Minutely());
//                                      ^^^^^^^^^^
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
                 "myDailyJob", 
                 () => CallRemoteService(dailyJobUrl)), Cron.Daily(0));

[...]
public void CallRemoteServiceQuickCheck(Uri url) {
    CallRemoteService(url));
}
```

and your log will look like

```
#238  Startup.CallRemoteServiceQuickCheck  7.234s  13 minutes ago  
#237  Startup.CallRemoteService            7.424s  23 minutes ago
```

Now for your other problem, it's more tricky.
I thinkthe easiest would be to add a new menu item "Filtered Succeded" in the left pane of the dashboard as follows where you init your app:

```
        Hangfire.Dashboard.JobsSidebarMenu.Items.Add(
            (rp) => {
                var filteredSuccededUrl = "[your_url_here]";
                return new Hangfire.Dashboard.MenuItem("FilteredSucceded",
                                                       filteredSuccededUrl); });
```

You can have this point to the url of your choice. Not ideal, but you have the source code of the succeeded page you can use to create your new page [here](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/Dashboard/Pages/SucceededJobs.cshtml).